# pip.main(["install", "--user", ...] not working

Tags: python, pip

This is Python 2.7.9, installed in a Debian Docker container. It is not using `virtualenv`. There's some things here that I could be doing fundamentally different. But regardless of that, I have the following very straightforward question:

Why doesn't this work?

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(["install", "--user", "httmock"])
...installs httmock...
>>> import httmock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named httmock
>>>
```

For comparison, this works fine:

```
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(["install", "httmock"])
...installs httmock...
>>> import httmock
>>>
```

Thank you.

Comment: A usual recipe: check `sys.path`. I doubt `~/.local/lib/...` is in the list of search paths by default.

Comment: I think you're right, it seems it isn't added until I install something with `--user`. Feel free to answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful comment from *user3159253* appeared to my question around the same time I found this myself. Since the other user isn't typing their answer, I will do it.

Apparently the local user site packages aren't automatically added to the search options for `import` until the next run of your application. To force it, add the local user site packages to the path *after* running `pip install --user ...`.

```
pip.main(["install", "--user", "httmock"])

home_folder = os.path.expanduser("~")
user_site_packages_folder = "{}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages".format(home_folder)
if user_site_packages_folder not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(user_site_packages_folder)
```

I imagine this is only necessary if there are already packages installed for the local user. I also imagine that the actual call to `sys.path.append` triggers special behavior, because adding the local user site packages folder to the path *before* running `pip` didn't work, but this is besides the point of this answer.